# Offline Map for Private Property with Navigation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, maps, mbtiles

I have an idea of building offline Map for my University Campus (its covering almost 3-4 miles). Like new students or guests can navigate to various blocks in campus. Student can see himself/herself marked on map at current location & can chose destination from pre-defined list of places and application will navigate them.

I have explored alot like **maptiles** can help me in showing maps. But is there any other efficient way of showing campus map ? And I have no idea how will I navigate user (since being a private property area is out of reach of Google's Maps (or some other) API).

Any suggestions will be helpful. :)

**EDITED**

Here is Google Map [link](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/MANDSAUR+INSTITUTE+OF+TECHNOLOGY/@24.0757982,75.0295181,17.83z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x39642bc4d39b30d7:0x79157bc5417c62b7) to my place.

I am studying [ArcGIS](http://www.arcgis.com/home/) from last few days, learned to create its 'geodatabase' using 'ArcGIS for Desktop' for rendering offline maps on iPhone.

However, now my concern is how to Navigate user.

And I will welcome any suggestion/idea for accomplishing it using any different approach.

Comment: What have you tried? You are not new to SO, so you must know that it is not a place to go for complete solutions and ideas :) At your place I'd begin with displaying the campus map (even as an image) and trying to map user's location from GPS on it and then work from it.

Comment: @Losiowaty Edited question. :)

Comment: I'd look here : https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/ `Get the SDK that lets you build mapping apps for Apple iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad devices! Integrate a wide range of mapping and GIS tasks online or offline, including editing, geocoding, **routing**, mapping, and data visualization.` - It seems that everything is there, in just 3 clicks.

Comment: I agree. :) But **routing** is not **navigation**. :)

Comment: I feel bad for doing this - https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/objective-c/guide/routing-task.htm, go to `Driving Directions`. Just put a little effort to looking through these docs.

Comment: @Losiowaty I had already gone through docs, sample codes etc. Its offline routing just returns path between 2 or more points on map. Doesn't navigates user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83969/discussion-between-losiowaty-and-ronit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that with MapBox.

MapBox is an alternative to GoogleMaps and supports offline maps.

> Mapbox iOS SDK
>   There are three methods available to the Mapbox iOS SDK
>   for offline maps. With cache-based methods, the RMTileCache for an
>   RMMapView can be configured to keep map tiles around based on their
>   count or based on their age in the cache.
>
> Caching based on previous user interaction
>
> Tiles are automatically cached once they are downloaded for display
>   based on the user’s panning and zooming of the map. For example, if a
>   user views the map, then zooms out, then zooms back in later when
>   offline, the original tiles will be present in cache and will display
>   without need for a network connection.
>
> Proactive background caching for certain map regions
>
> Using RMTileCache and the RMTileCacheBackgroundDelegate protocol, the
>   developer can enable the user to download a certain bounding box and
>   zoom range in the background in advance of actually displaying them on
>   screen. Callbacks trigger, allowing the developer to report progress
>   to the user or even to cancel a download in progress.
>
> Tiles that already exist in cache will be skipped over during this
>   background download instead of re-downloaded.
>
> MBTiles prepackaged tiles
>
> Using the MBTiles format for map tile storage, developers can build
>   apps that read the tiles straight out of the MBTiles file and do not
>   ever need a network connection. Since MBTiles is an open format, files
>   can be created manually or with TileMill, as well as many other
>   applications and utilities such as mbutil.

You need the last one (i.e. `MBTiles prepackaged tiles`).

Source: https://www.mapbox.com/help/ios-offline/

Comment: Yes, it seems its only the best option out there.

Comment: Mapbox doesn't yet provide Custom Routing on Custom Routes.

Comment: Please contact them. Maybe they will suggest you a better way to achieve your goal

Comment: How about trimaps.com ? However, they too do-not provide routing.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that they don't support routing? Do you mean a directions API?

Comment: Yes, direction API in offline mode.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think that you can find something like that.

Comment: Thnxx.. for your support. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you go the OpenStreetMap way (map your property directly in OpenStreeMap) then you can also use the [Scout SDK](http://developer.skobbler.com/).

It's OSM based and provides full support for offline maps, offline routing & TBT navigation. If you properly connect the road segments then the SDK will be able to create car, bike & pedestrian routes on your data.

While not free, the Scout SDK has a free tier that might be large enough for your particular needs (if not you'll move to a "pay-as-you" model)