# Restrict the dragging of SKMapView to a certain city

Tags: objective-c, skmaps

I am trying to restrict dragging of `SKMapView` to a certain city.

Here is what I have tried, I had gone through Doc References and open source code. Seems like `SKBoundingBox` does that.

But this piece of code doesn't work. It still allows user to pan everywhere.

```
SKBoundingBox *boundingBox = [SKBoundingBox boundingBoxWithTopLeftCoordinate:topLeftCoordinate bottomRightCoordinate:bottomRightCoordinate];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is no integrated support for this, you can do a workaround.

The file from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/669vuqnfu9ivhwh/MapDisplayViewController.m?dl=0) should replace the one from the Public SDK demo app for viewing the workaround (MapDisplayViewController.m).

The idea is that you can get the bounding box information of a city/country from the Maps.json provided by us. Then you need to implement the following callback:

```
- (void)mapView:(SKMapView *)mapView didChangeToRegion:(SKCoordinateRegion)region { 
    if (self.bbox) { 
        if ([self.bbox containsLocation:region.center]) { 
            self.previousRegion = region; 
        } else { 
            [self.mapView animateToLocation:self.previousRegion.center withDuration:0.2]; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

This implementation ensures that when the user pans out of the bounding box of a city/country he will be moved back to the previous region contained by the bounding box.

**Zoom level restrictions:** restricting the zoom level is possible through the zoomLimits property of the SKMapsSettings:

```
   SKMapZoomLimits zoomLimits; 
    zoomLimits.mapZoomLimitMin = 5.0f; 
    zoomLimits.mapZoomLimitMax = 14.0f; 
    self.mapView.settings.zoomLimits = zoomLimits;
```

Comment: Can SKMap help me in achieving this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513807/offline-map-for-private-property-with-navigation-in-ios ?

Comment: I've added an answer to the question you were pointing to - if the data in available in OSM then the Scout SDK can fully work with it offline